# How do you setup a webhook from bitbucket to AWS Codebuild to trigger only on merge to dev branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, webhooks, aws-codebuild

AWS codebuild using Bitbucket source:

Under "Primary source webhook events Info"

and then under: "Start a build under these conditions"

How do you setup the HEAD_REF and BASE_REF properly to trigger a build only on a merge from any branch to the dev branch?

I have tried `^refs/heads/dev$` in the BASE_Ref field, but that didn't work. I have also confirmed that codebuild is connecting to bitbucket:

`{
  "response": "No build triggered for specified payload",
  "statusCode": 200
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for using AWS CodeBuild! For your use case, here's the sample steps:

1. Go to AWS CodeBuild console, set up webhook for your Bitbucket source project. Put "^refs/heads/dev$" in BASE_REF text box, and choose PULL_REQUEST_MERGED for the event type.
2. Once the webhook is created, check on Bitbucket page and find your webhook, and click edit. In "Triggers" -> "Pull Request", make sure you checked "Merged" checkbox. This makes sure Bitbucket will deliver pull request merge event payloads.
3. Merge a pull request, and in the webhook request logs, look for requests with event type "pullrequest:fulfilled". This webhook event should trigger a CodeBuild build.

Please note a Bitbucket pull request merge event will deliver two webhook events, one with event type "pullrequest:fulfilled" and one with "repo:push". With the setting above, CodeBuild will build on the "pullrequest:fulfilled" payload.

Comment: what changes do i make in BASE_REF to start build only when a pull request is created, updated or reopened?